# Compile from inside Sublime using MSBuild package

Tags: msbuild, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I installed the sublime [MSBuild package](https://github.com/tillig/SublimeMSBuild). I have a sublime project setup with the directory structure that includes the solution and visual studio projects.

`rootdir/src/codehere
rootdir/.build/vcproj/projectshere`

I try to build the project from a source file in the src directory by hitting `ctr+b`. I get this error in the output window.

`rootdir\src\foo.cpp(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`

I didn't see any documentation in the MSBuild package for pointing it to the specific visual studio solution.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is clear on this:

```
Build system: Execute the currently loaded MSBuild script and capture the results in the output pane
```

In other words, open the project or soltuion you want to build, then hit Ctrl-b

*edit* looked into this a bit and the main reason it is done the way it is is just because it makes the most sense: in ST, just like in most other text editors, there's always one 'active' file on which commands are invoked.

That being said there might be a solution for you by creating a cutsom Sublime 'build system'. Combined info from [SublimeMsBuild](https://github.com/tillig/SublimeMSBuild/blob/master/MSBuild.sublime-build) itself and from the [Sublime build system syntax pages](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html): select `Tools->Build System->New Build System` and paste the following into the file:

```
{
  "shell_cmd" : "msbuild",
  "working_dir" : "$project_path",
  "windows":
  {
    "path": "%PATH%;%WINDIR%\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v4.0.30319;%WINDIR%\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v3.5;%WINDIR%\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\\v2.0.50727"
  },
}
```

and then save it appropriately. This will give you a new build system which can be selected from the `Tools->Build System` menu and when executed will invoke msbuild in the directory of the current Sublime project's path. Now invokation of msbuild doesn't depend on the current file anymore, instead on the current project. So all you have to do is save a sublime project into the directory where you also have your msbuild solution/project, open the project and then hit Ctrl-b whenever you want.